# Django - Multiple Choice Field - Form Not saving

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, multiplechoicefield

I have a Django application and want to display multiple choice checkboxes in a user's profile. They will then be able to select multiple items.

But I am not able to save the form that is created. Can anyone help?

My models.py looks like this:

```
    class multiChoice(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    Options = (
                ("AUT", "Australia"),
                ("DEU", "Germany"),
                ("NLD", "Neitherlands")
                )
    Countries = models.ManyToManyField(Choices,choices=Options)

User.multiChoice=property(lambda u:multiChoice.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

forms.py:

```
class multiChoiceForm(forms.Form):
    Countries = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Choices.objects.all(), required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    class Meta:
        model=multiChoice
        fields=("Countries")
```

views.py:

```
def multiChoice_v1(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = multiChoiceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            countries = form.cleaned_data.get('countries')
            countries.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin/')
    else:
        form=multiChoiceForm()
    args={}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form']=form

    return render_to_response('editprofile_v2.html', args)
```

urls.py - snippet of the multi-choice view alone:

```
url(r'^accounts/profile_v2/$', 'guitarclubapp.views.multiChoice_v1'),
```

editprofile_v2.html:

```
<html>

 <form method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
  <label> Countries </label>
        <select name="Countries" id="Countries" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="AUT" selected="selected">Austria</option>
            <option value="DEU" selected="selected">Germany</option>
            <option value="NLD" selected="selected">Netherlands</option>
        </select>

    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
</html>
```

Is there anything that I am missing out (or) have done anything wrong?

Should I change the way I am defining my model?

Any help or references would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are quite a few things wrong here You are certainly getting at least one error message, which you should read and also post.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daniel, I was getting few errors like "Attribute Error", "Import Error", etc,. But I some how managed to clear them and I am not getting any errors for the above code. It would be very helpful if you can point out the things that are wrong in my code. Thanks again.